# how to expand uitableviewcell height using swift with animation like in this gif?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, animation

I have a `UITableView` in my app, I want to have the cell expanded to reveal some details like the attached gif.

What do you think is the best way to do this?
I have seen people talking about Objc-C way, but how to do it in swift?

- the ticking circle resembles a touch.

EDIT :

I managed to have this working, but how to change animation speed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just increase the height(of the clicked cell) and call the below methods.

`table.beginUpdates()
 table.endUpdates()`

Comment: I want it animated not suddenly expanded.

Comment: yes, it worked but how to change the animation speed?